# Finding a Specific Date with SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access

I'm trying to search in an database for records with a specific date. I've tried to search in the following ways:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE CAL_DATE=01/01/2015
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE CAL_DATE='01/01/2015'
```

I'm working with an Access database, and in the table, the dates are showing in the same format (01/01/2015). Is there something I'm missing in the SQL statement?

Comment: What is the datatype of the CAL_DATE column?

Comment: Access requires your date to be surrounded by pound signs (or hashtags, for those under-30's).  So, you want **WHERE CAL_DATE = #01/01/2015#**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the options below should work:

Format the date directly in your query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE CAL_DATE=#01/01/2015#;
```

The DateValue function will convert a string to a date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE CAL_DATE=DateValue('01/01/2015');
```

The CDate function will convert a value to a date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE CAL_DATE=CDate('01/01/2015');
```

The DateSerial function will return a date given the year, month, and day.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE CAL_DATE=DateSerial(2015, 1, 1);
```

See the following page for more information on the above functions: [techonthenet.com](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the # # function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CDATE function on your filter:

```
WHERE CAL_DATE = CDATE('01/01/2015')
```

This will ensure that your input is of date datatype, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * from Table1 WHERE (CDATE(ColumnDate) BETWEEN #03/26/2015# AND #03/19/2015#)

if this works .. vote for it.. we use above query for searching records from 26th march to 19 the march.. change the dates accordingly..

Answer (score -2):

SELECT * from Table1 WHERE (CDATE(ColumnDate) BETWEEN #03/26/2015# AND #03/19/2015#)

if this works .. vote for it.. we use above query for searching records from 26th march to 19 the march.. change the dates accordingly..

Comment: No reason to vote for this. It makes no sense to apply CDate on a field of data type datetime. Actually, it will even fail if the field has the value of Null.